# ghci not loading function from file

Tags: haskell, ghci

In test.hs, I have:

```
doubleMe x = x + x
```

In ghci, I type:

```
Prelude> :l test
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> doubleMe 9

<interactive>:1:0: Not in scope: `doubleMe'
*Main>
```

Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you're loading the right test.hs? Maybe you're in the wrong directory. Or maybe you didn't save test.hs after adding the definition of doubleMe.

Comment: I had created a folder in Desktop instead of a shortcut to a folder.

Answer (score 32):

My guess is that you have defined a main function in your source file.

If you have defined a `main` function, loading the module with `:l test` won't import any functions but `main`. In that case you can load it by prepending an asterix to the module name: `:l *test`.
The reason is that the compiled binary will hide non-exported top-level functions. Prepending an asterix forces GHCi to ignore the precompiled module (test) and interprete the source file instead (test.hs).

```
[jkramer/sgi5k:.../haskell]# cat test.hs 

main = do
    print $ doubleMe 2

doubleMe x = x + x

[jkramer/sgi5k:.../haskell]# ghc --make test
[jkramer/sgi5k:.../haskell]# ghci
[...some messages...]
>> :l test
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
>> :t doubleMe

<interactive>:1:0: Not in scope: `doubleMe'
>> :l *test
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
>> :t doubleMe
doubleMe :: (Num a) => a -> a
```

Check these links for further information:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghci-compiled.html
   http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope

Comment: This wasn't the op's problem, but you fixed my problem. Thanks for the *module_name trick.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. First off, after you load test, the prompt will look like *Main>, instead of >>. Also I get an error message telling me <command line>:
    Could not find module `*fadetoblack':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Answer (score 5):

1. Remove test.hi and test.o from the directory and then try `ghci test`. [Sometimes when I run `ghc file.hs` (and not `ghc --make file.hs`) it gives undefined reference error, but creates such files that are read by `ghci` later. Maybe this is a bug.]
2. Try

   ```
   :cd "<path to your file>"
   :l test
   :browse
   ```

   in ghci. What is the result?

Comment: On OS X 10.11.6 and GHCI 8.2.2 you do not have to use double quotes at `<path to your file>`. You can try `:cd <path to your file>`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, too - and in case anyone else runs into it and stumbles across this page, my issue was that the VM I was running GHCI in was out of disk space - prompting it to try and load an empty file each time.